# Ajax request returning undefined value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a simple JQuery Ajax request for external api data:

```
function loadArticle(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&apiKey=XXXX',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET'
    }).done(function(response){

        var res = response.articles[0].title;
        console.log(res);
        addDivOne(res);

    }).fail(function(){
        console.log('error no response')
    }).always(function(){
        console.log('always')
    })
}
```

I need to add **"res"** value to another function who append div in my HTML page like this.

```
function addDivOne(resone) {

      $("#content-div").append('<li class="new-div list-group-item" id="1">' + resone + 
     '<div class = "row" style="min-height: 75px;">' + 
     '<button type="button" class="btn pull-right btn-danger btn-close">Delete</button>' +
     '</div>' +
     '</li>');   
}
```

The problem is that when I call addDivOne() function the value for **"resone"** is *undefined*.
How can I display the real **"res"** value?

P.S. my response:

```
{"status":"ok","source":"techcrunch","sortBy":"top","articles":[{"author":"Sarah Perez","title":"Black Friday online sales to hit a record-breaking $3 billion, over $1 billion from mobile","description":"Black Friday online shopping is continuing to grow, and this Friday was another record-breaking day. According to a new report out this evening from Adobe,..","url":"http://social.techcrunch.com/2016/11/25/black-friday-online-sales-to-hit-a-record-breaking-3-billion-over-1-billion-from-mobile/","urlToImage":"https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2016/05/shutterstock_341086469.jpg?w=764&amp;h=400&amp;crop=1","publishedAt":"2016-11-26T00:44:17Z"},{"author":"Sarah Buhr","title":"Siren Care makes a “smart” sock to track diabetic health","description":"Diabetic health tracking startup Siren Care has created smart socks that use temperature sensors to detect inflammation -- and therefore injury -- in..","url":"http://social.techcrunch.com/2016/11/25/siren-care-makes-a-smart-sock-to-track-diabetic-health/","urlToImage":"https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/1609_sirensocks_with-ap.jpg?w=764&amp;h=400&amp;crop=1","publishedAt":"2016-11-25T22:05:22Z"},{"author":"Connie Loizos","title":"Peter Thiel taps a principal at Founders Fund for Trump’s transition team","description":"Peter Thiel is famously loyal to his employees, and vice versa. Many of the dozens of people employed by his venture firm, Founders Fund, once worked for..","url":"http://social.techcrunch.com/2016/11/25/peter-thiel-taps-a-principal-at-founders-fund-for-trumps-transition-team/","urlToImage":"https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2016/07/gettyimages-578544740.jpg?w=764&amp;h=400&amp;crop=1","publishedAt":"2016-11-25T16:21:10Z"},{"author":"Ingrid Lunden","title":"Payments provider Stripe has raised another $150M at a $9B valuation","description":"Stripe -- the company that lets websites and apps incorporate payments services by way of an API and a few lines of code -- has raised another round of..","url":"http://social.techcrunch.com/2016/11/25/payments-provider-stripe-has-raised-another-150-at-a-9b-valuation/","urlToImage":"https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2015/06/kk.png?w=321&amp;h=226&amp;crop=1","publishedAt":"2016-11-25T12:16:17Z"}]}
```

Comment: add sample response from server in question please.

Comment: What does `response` contain?

Comment: Have you made sure `response.articles[0]` has a `title` property?

Comment: I want to see your response with my specs.

Comment: The response is correct, because it return correct value in the console. I want to call res into another  function, but the result is undefined?

Comment: for giggles, what happens if you change `addDivOne(res);` to `addDivOne("hello world");`

Comment: in that case, `resone` in the argument to the function is spelled different to the `resone` in the body of the function ... or you have another `addDivOne` function definition which has some sort of error like that ... try `console.log(addDiveOne + "");` before you call it, and see if the function in the console is what you expect

Comment: You might have 2 definitions for `addDivOne` function? 
Try calling it seperatly outside of the ajax call with some static value like `addDivOne('My Name is blah blah)`. If this works than :-(

Comment: Also what is the output of `console.log(res);` once the ajax response is received

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loadArticle function, what does console.log(res) give you as output?

If 'res' has some value, then getting value of resone as undefined does not make sense.

Also make sure that addDivOne function is not called before you want it to..as in not before the success of ajax inside loadArtice.

This might help..
Put one condition inside addDivOne function, to append the value to div only if resone has some value..(ex if `resone !== undefined` then do the appending)